# How to reconcile first and last record in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, logic

I have a table in my SQL database that tracks an employee's in time and out time. A typical record would look like this

```
Id           Device               DateTime                    EmployeeId    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            InReader             2013/05/05 08:00:00         1
2            InReader             2013/05/05 08:00:05         1
3            InReader             2013/05/05 08:01:00         2
4            InReader             2013/05/05 08:02:00         3
5            InReader             2013/05/05 08:03:00         4
6            OutReader            2013/05/05 17:00:00         1
7            OutReader            2013/05/05 17:05:05         2
8            OutReader            2013/05/05 17:05:10         2
9            OutReader            2013/05/05 17:10:00         3
10           OutReader            2013/05/05 17:30:00         4
```

Id is just an auto increment column
Device is the device that they tapped their staff card on, to clock in/or out
DateTime is the time that they tapped their staff card

I would like to know, at the end of the day, when I'm generating a report, how can I reconcile their in-time with out-time, such that the output may look like this:

```
Employee Id            In time                    Out time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                      2013/05/05 08:00:00        2013/05/05 17:00:00
2                      2013/05/05 08:01:00        2013/05/05 17:05:10
3                      2013/05/05 08:02:00        2013/05/05 17:10:00
4                      2013/05/05 08:03:00        2013/05/05 17:30:00
```

Caveats:
- Note that Employee 1 has 2 records for "InReader", I would want to take the earlier record
- Employee 2 has 2 records for "OutReader", I would want to take only his latest record

How do I reconcile the IN and OUT records using LINQ? (or TSQL if it's not possible in LINQ)

Comment: Will the records only be for one day? are they wiped nightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made you this query, and tested in LinqPad. I'll give you the full code so you can try it yourself.

The query itself:

```
tracks.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
      .Select(x => new 
            {
                EmployeeId = x.Key,
                InTime = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Device.Equals("InReader")).DateTime,
                OutTime = x.LastOrDefault(y => y.Device.Equals("OutReader")).DateTime
            })
```

The full code sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var tracks = new[]
    {
        new Track{Id = 1, Device = "InReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,0,0), EmployeeId = 1},
        new Track{Id = 2, Device = "InReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,0,5), EmployeeId = 1},
        new Track{Id = 3, Device = "InReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,1,0), EmployeeId = 2},
        new Track{Id = 4, Device = "InReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,2,0), EmployeeId = 3},
        new Track{Id = 5, Device = "InReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,8,3,0), EmployeeId = 4},

        new Track{Id = 6, Device = "OutReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,0,0), EmployeeId = 1},
        new Track{Id = 7, Device = "OutReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,5,5), EmployeeId = 2},
        new Track{Id = 8, Device = "OutReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,5,10), EmployeeId = 2},
        new Track{Id = 9, Device = "OutReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,10,0), EmployeeId = 3},
        new Track{Id = 10, Device = "OutReader", DateTime = new DateTime(2013,5,5,17,30,0), EmployeeId = 4},
    };

        // the Query
        tracks
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .Select(x => new 
        {
            EmployeeId = x.Key,
            InTime = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Device.Equals("InReader")).DateTime,
            OutTime = x.LastOrDefault(y => y.Device.Equals("OutReader")).DateTime
        })
}

public class Track
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Device { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the OP needs _daily_ in/out times (this will give the first and last record per employee for all times, and also assumes the records are ordered by datetime).

Comment: Ah yes. That would require some grouping to the day in DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Use `Min, Max` aggregate to returns the smallest or largest element in the sequence and use `GroupBy` for ordering.

```
var result=YourTableRowCollection.GroupBy(x=>x.EmployeeId)
                            .Select(x=>new { EmployeeId=x.Key,
                                             InTime=x.Min(t=>DateTime.Parse(t.InTime)).ToString(),
                                             OutTime=x.Max(t=>DateTime.Parse(t.OutTime)).ToString()});
```

Comment: But does this handle duplicate entry or exit records by the same employee?

Comment: @PapyrusBit, Code is modified and let me know for anything further

Comment: So what happens when entries are added for the next day ? Also what if a person clocks in one day and works past midnight ?

Comment: Maybe it would be best to include the device in your algorithm.. encase someone forgets to clock in but clocks out etc

Comment: @PaulZahra, This is something you have to implement since you are the best person to know all business cases such as (a)what if employee sneak through backdoor without swipe out or (b) what happen if employee continue to stay at office ( as Christian Dietz suggested) for another day.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x = from current in context.Employess
                let firstRecord = current.Where(c=> c.Track.Device == "InReader").OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).First()
                let lastRecord = current.Where(c=> c.Track.Device == "OutReader").OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).Last()
                select{
                    // do something
                }
```

Something like that above should do the trick.

Comment: This code could throw an error because you are using `First()` and `Last()`. I recommend using the `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()` methods

Comment: hence the phrase "Something like that", its a push into a direction, not a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = table.Where(e => e.Device == "InReader")
                    .GroupBy(e => e.EmployeeId)
                        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d.DateTime).First())
            .Join(
            table.Where(e => e.Device == "OutReader")
                    .GroupBy(e => e.EmployeeId)
                        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).First()), 
            t => t.EmployeeId, t => t.EmployeeId,(t, i) => new { Id = t.EmployeeId, In = t.DateTime, Out = i.DateTime });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you know your employee's ID (or may be you are going through a list) and the date at which you're generating your report, so first thing you need to do is to get your employee's in and out times of the day with sth. like this:

```
 //first second of the day
 DateTime firstSecondOfTheDay = dateToCheck.Subtract(dateToCheck.TimeOfDay);
 //last second of the day 
 TimeSpan endOfDay = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
 DateTime lastSecondOfTheDay = firstSecondOfTheDay.Add(endOfDay);
 var employeeDayInOut = from emp in context.Employess
                        where (emp.DateTime >= firstSecondOfTheDay) &
                              (emp.DateTime <= lastSecondOfTheDay) &
                              (emp.EmployeeId == idToCheck)
                        select emp;
```

You could also easily rewrite this query in order to obtain all employees times of the day, and filter by EmployeeId lately (it depends on what is better for your case).

And after that you can obtain easily from your employee's in and out times of the day the date you need for your report like this:

```
  employeeDayInOut.Max(emp => emp.DateTime);
  employeeDayInOut.Min(emp => emp.DateTime);
```